# Angular, странная ошибка Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error при использовании APP_INITIALIZER

Tags: javascript, firefox, angular

Я хочу использовать `APP_INITIALIZER` для загрузки информации об авторизации при старте приложения. Я добавил `APP_INITIALIZER` в `AppModule`:

```
 providers: [
        {
            provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
            useFactory: init,
            deps: [AuthService],
            multi: true
        }
    ]
```

Моя `init` функция:

```
export function init(authService: AuthService) {
    return () => {
        return authService.loadSecurityInfo(true).toPromise();
    };
}
```

Метод `loadSecurityInfo` выглядит так:

```
loadSecurityInfo(reconstituteSecurity = false): Observable<SecurityInfo> {
    console.log(`Loading SecurityInfo - Reconstitute security? ${reconstituteSecurity}`);

    return this.http
        .get<any>(this.securityInfoUrl, {headers: this.headers})
        .pipe(
            map(body => {
                this._securityInfo = new SecurityInfo();
                this._securityInfo.isAuthenticationEnabled = body.authenticationEnabled;
                this._securityInfo.isAuthenticated = body.authenticated;
                this._securityInfo.username = body.username;
                this._securityInfo.roles = body.roles as string[];

                console.log(`Getting security info: ${JSON.stringify(this.securityInfo)}`);
                return this._securityInfo;
            }),
            catchError(this.errorReporter.handleError('loadSecurityInfo', null))
        );
}
```

Когда я запускаю приложение и пытаюсь обновить страницу, нажав F5 быстро, например, два раза, я получаю ошибку в консоли браузера:

```
Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error
loadSecurityInfo failed: Backend returned code 0, status: undefined, error list: undefined
zUnb/Y</e.prototype.handleError/<
http://localhost:8080/main.ba74b710245ba9a3c361.js:1:1433305
9Z1F/u</t.prototype.error
m
http://localhost:8080/polyfills.855d06b353079dbdbf17.js:1:20756
b
```

Если я нажимаю F5 медленно, когда предыдущее обновление страницы отработало, ошибки нет! Я сломал себе мозг, почему происходит эта ошибка? Ошибка происходит **только** в браузере `Firefox 60.4.0esr` возможно и ниже, на последних версий браузеров `Firefox` и хром-нет ошибок.

Я использую `Angular 6.1.10`

**UPDATE:**

handleError:

```
handleError<T>(operation = 'operation', result?: T) {
        return (error: any): Observable<T> => {

            // TODO: send the error to remote logging infrastructure
            console.error(error); // log to console instead

            const message = traslateErrorToMessage(error);
            console.error(`${operation} failed: ${message}`);

            // go to error page
            window.location.href = 'assets/pages/error.html';

            // Let the app keep running by returning an empty result.
            return of(result as T);
        };
    }

function traslateErrorToMessage(error: any) {
    let message;
    if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
        message = `A client-side or network error: ${error.error.message}`;
    } else {
        message = `Backend returned code ${error.status}, status: ${error.error.status}, `
            + `error list: ${error.error.errors}`;
    }
    return message;
}
```

Вызовы сети:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

securityInfoUrl здесь вообще даже не вызвался!

Ошибка в консоле:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Заголовки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPDATE:**
Я убрал обращение к API при старте приложения, но ошибка осталась и возникает уже на другом обращение при тех же самых действия (несколько раз нажать F5), т.е. получается проблема не `APP_INITIALIZER`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: покажите `errorReporter.handleError`

Comment: добавил, обновил вопрос

Comment: `Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error` - это ошибка CORS, у вас сервер возвращает нужные хедеры?

Comment: Да, это первое что я проверил. Корс тут вообще не используется, я запускаю все на одном домене и порту!

Comment: Я добавил скрин Сети из браузера. securityInfoUrl даже вообще не вызвался ни разу. Сразу свалился с ошибкой.

Comment: а в хедерах у вас что и можно еще скрин ошибки именно из консоли, просто текст сложнее читать, эта ошибка у вас и в продакшене и деве, или только в проде?

Comment: Я обновил вопрос. Здесь я просто два раза нажал сразу F5 и опять получил ошибку, но в этом случае вызов `info` отработал, приложил заголовки, потом сразу упал с ошибкой. Ошибку в консоле тоже приложил. Ошибка возникает в любом режиме хоть в dev, хоть в prod

Comment: Что удивительно, ни одной сетевой ошибки, все со статусом 200.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88540/discussion-between-all-safe-and-overthesanity).